# VBA format date to get the previous month

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am fairly new at VBA and this seems like an easy task. I am just trying to get the current date substituting the current month for the previous one and a day constant as 21 so the result will have to be   yyyy - (m-1) - 21

so far I had a couple of ideas and they work partially

```
Sub Test_Date()
     Dim x As String
     Dim p As String
   p = Format(Date, "mm") - 1
   x = Format(Date, "yyyy-" p "-21")
End Sub
```

if I MsgBx "p" comesback as what I want but, I dont know the correct syntax to concatenate them into one string

also

```
Sub Test_Date()
   Dim x As String
     x = Format(Date, "yyyy-(Format(Date, "mm") - 1)-21")
End Sub
```

Comment: `DateAdd("m", -1, Date)` will give you what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try this:

```
Function LastMonth() As Date
    Dim d As Date
        d = DateAdd("m", -1, Date)
    LastMonth = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), 21)
End Function
```

**Edit:**

Format the returned date as needed:

```
Sub Test()
    MsgBox Format(LastMonth, "yyyy-mm-dd")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you kostas that was very close, except for the date comes back as mm/21/yyyy  and I need it as yyyy-mm-21 .  never the less great suggestion

Comment: the last line of code had some errors,   I tried        

Function LastMonth() As Date
    Dim d As Date
        d = DateAdd("m", -1, Date)
    LastMonth = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), 21)
    d = Format(LastMonth, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    
    MsgBox d
    
End Function             

with the same result  "8/21/2017"

Comment: Hey Kostas! I got it ... just had to change the calling of variable d from date to string.    Thank yo uso much for the help brother, have a good day!

Comment: You need to handle the format outside the function. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DateSerial`.

This accepts a year, month and day as its input and kicks out the date based on that.

So, `DateSerial(2017,9,22)` will give todays date.
To get the 21st of last month you'd use

```
DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 21)
```

`Year(Date)` returns 2017, `Month(Date)` returns 9.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if date = 2017/01/01, wouldn't that return 2017/12/21? Where it should be 2016/12/21?

Comment: Hi Darren. It also works to change the dates into the right values but on a wrong order as the last suggestion comes out as mm/dd/yyyy instead of yyyy-mm-dd . Thanks for your comment

Comment: @KostasK.  No, `Dateserial(2017,1-1,21)` returns 21 Dec 2016 and `DateSerial(2017,-13,1)` returns 01 Nov 2015.

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook Thanks for clarifying this Darren.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @Fabsklo by _change the dates into the right values but on a wrong order_  The code `Sheet1.Range("A1") = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 21)` will place the date in the A1 using your local format settings.  You can then change the format of the cell to `yyyy-mm-dd` so Excel still understands it's a date.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dateadd function (https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php):

```
DateAdd( interval, number, date )

or

DateAdd("m", 5, "22/11/2003")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub Test_Date()
    Dim d As Date
    d = "22-09-2017"
    d = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d) - 1, 21)
End Sub
```